# Rails 5 API - Load static pages even if connection to database cannot be established

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am struggling for a solution since 2 days now.

I have a Rails API which is connected to a remote MySQL server. The problem is when I take the MySQL server offline, my entire App stops working. I want a solution where my app can gracefully return "Database unavailable" message as JSON to any REST requests when the database is offline.

At the moment, as soon as the database server is offline, I get ***Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXXX.com'*** in development and ***500 internal server*** error in Production.

My database.yml is

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: XXXX
  password: XXXX
  host:  XXXX.com
  port: 3306
  encoding: utf8mb4

development:
  <<: *default
  database: geodatabase

test:
  <<: *default
  database: geodatabase_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: geodatabase_production
```

I remember some years ago working on rails, any database problems would still render static pages normally. I don't understand why it isn't working now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When database connection does not work then Rails throw this exception
`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`

You can handle this exception using below code

In the `application_controller.rb` file you can put below the line. It should be first line.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished, with: :db_connection_error

def db_connection_error
  render json: { error: "DB connection refused" }, status: 503
end
```